# Forcing highlighter to html in VI when it fails to recognize an input file

Tags: vi, syntax-highlighting

I'm having trouble editing HTML in an older version of VI(M). 
`VIM - Vi IMproved 6.3 (2004 June 7, compiled [...] 2005)`. When reading .sh shell scripts there is no problem, though.

It doesn't recognize html files for syntax highlighting. Is there any to force a particular language interpretation even if the editor doesn't recognize it? In emacs, `M-x html-mode` informs the editor what language you're actually editing.

I can't upgrade because this is running in servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Vim is installed correctly the command is `:set filetype=html`, see `:help filetype` for more information.

You can shorten it to `:set ft=html`.

Happy retro-vimming!

Answer (score 1):

You can force vim to use the language you want with

```
:setf html
```

[See](http://jamesreubenknowles.com/set-vim-syntax-language-270)

Comment: Thanks, 10 months later I've noticed "setf" is easier to type. I ended up automating the original issue via custom definitions based on extensions: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype